# jQuery .post Post Elements

Tags: php, jquery, .post

Here is my code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
$.post("handlers/request.php");

}                       
</script>

<form action="handlers/request.php" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="request">
<a href="javascript: submitform()">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://google.com" />
</a>
</form>
```

In a separate PHP file (handers/request.php) I have a simple:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
```

It isn't picking this up. Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually passing any data through.

```
$.post("handlers/request.php", { url: $("[name='url']").val() }, function(data){
  console.log( data );
});
```

Note the second parameter, it's an object which will carry our values over to the server-side PHP script. The `url` key will become `$_POST['url']` on the server-end, and will contain our value from the `[name='url']` form input.

Additionally, when binding this functionality to an anchor-click, avoid the following:

```
<a href="javascript: submitform()">
```

Instead, go with something more along the lines of:

```
<a class="submit" href="enablejs.html">Submit</a>
```

Then, within your JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  $("form#request").on("click", "a.submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("handlers/request.php", { url: $("[name='url']").val() }, function(data){
      console.log( data );
    });
  });
});
```

It's always good to keep your JavaScript out of your HTML.

Comment: When you need to pass multiple variables does it look like this? $.post("handlers/request.php", { url: $("[name='url']").val(), title: $("[name='title']").val() }, function(data){ console.log( data );

Comment: @ChrisOlson Yes, your data object is constructed of keys and values, like this `{ key: 'value', otherKey: 5 }`.

Answer (score 0):

On a simple level, you need to:

- pass some data to the Ajax page, which your code doesn't.
- decide what to do once your data has been passed.

The syntax for $.post goes like:

```
jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

so it would be:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

to pass simple JavaScript variables, or:

```
$.post("test.php", $("#request").serialize());
```

to pass a whole form with id "request", like yours.
You need to specify a callback function if your `test.php` page returns some code.

Besides, your implementation of the HTML is somewhat messy. There's no sense in putting a hidden input in an `A` tag. Try something like:

```
<form action="handlers/request.php" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="request">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://google.com" />
    <input type="button" onclick="submitform();" value="Submit" />
</form>

function submitform() {
    $.post("handlers/request.php", $("#request").serialize());
}
```